# SharePoint Images not rendered in custom email

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, smtpclient

I am sending out an HTML e-mail from an event receiver hooked to a Pages library. The `PublishingPageContent` field which is filled with HTML values doesn't render the images when the email get sent to outlook.

This is my code below

```
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@sharepoint.local", "Recipient"));
                message.From = new MailAddress("xxx@sharepoint.local", "Sharepoint Test Emailer");
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = properties.ListItem.Title;
                message.Body = properties.ListItem["PublishingPageContent"].ToString();
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("192.168.10.0");
                client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine so there's two areas to check here:

1. Is there potentially a rule on the Exchange server that's removing these? Maybe client based settings that are blocking images?
2. Have you checked the value of `ListItem["PublishingPageContent"].ToString()` to make sure that it's working as expected at runtime?